# Json Querying using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

I have a Json data stored in SQL server:

```
{  
"group":{  
  "operator":"AND",
  "rules":[  
     {  
        "condition":"=",
        "field":"F1",
        "table":"ATT",
        "data":"TEST",
        "readOnly":false,
        "hidden":false,
        "$$hashKey":"005"
     },
     {  
        "condition":"=",
        "field":"CLASS",
        "table":"OBJ",
        "data":"A1",
        "readOnly":false,
        "hidden":false,
        "$$hashKey":"008"
     },
     {  
        "group":{  
           "operator":"AND",
           "rules":[  
              {  
                 "condition":"=",
                 "field":"F1",
                 "table":"ATT",
                 "data":"TEST2",
                 "readOnly":false,
                 "hidden":false,
                 "$$hashKey":"00D"
              },
              {  
                 "condition":"=",
                 "field":"F1",
                 "table":"ATT",
                 "data":"TEST3",
                 "readOnly":false,
                 "hidden":false,
                 "$$hashKey":"00G"
              }
           ]
        },
        "table":"",
        "$$hashKey":"009"
     }
  ]
}
}
```

How can I get the count of the element field having value =`F1` using SQL?

Comment: json data stored in SQL server????

Comment: @N1gthm4r3: [Yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server).

Comment: What do you mean by "the count"? Do you want to know how many `condition`s have the value `F1` for the `field` property?

Comment: Json is stored in SQL server @N1gthm4r3

Comment: You are right  @JeroenMostert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"group":{
    "operator":"AND",
    "rules":
        [{"condition":"=",
        "field":"F1",
        "table":"ATT",
        "data":"TEST",
        "readOnly":false,
        "hidden":false,
        "$$hashKey":"005"},
        {"condition":"=",
        "field":"BANKID",
        "table":"ATT",
        "data":"A1",
        "readOnly":false,
        "hidden":false,
        "$$hashKey":"008"}]}}';

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.group.rules')
WHERE JSON_VALUE(value, '$.field') = 'F1'
```

You have a table, you say? `CROSS APPLY` is your friend:

```
SELECT T.[data], rules.F1_count
FROM T CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS F1_count
    FROM OPENJSON(jsonData, '$.group.rules')
    WHERE JSON_VALUE(value, '$.field') = 'F1'
) AS rules
```

Comment: Above code works, but  here we are getting the json in a variable , how ever my data stays in a table with  N number of rows with the various json strings[ same format] , so i need to  apply the above logic on all records items to get the count. how to achieve that

Comment: @AbrahamMathewAjoy: `CROSS APPLY`, see update. In this case, a subquery would also work since we're only getting one value, but `CROSS APPLY` is more general.

Comment: Yes we are close at the solution , how ever if we have multiple  groups elements , it is not counting from the second group item {"group":{"operator":"AND","rules":[{"condition":"=","field":"TSCREATED","table":"OBJ","data":"2","readOnly":false,"hidden":false,"$$hashKey":"005"},
 {"group":{"operator":"AND","rules":[{"condition":"=","field":"CLASS","table":"OBJ","data":"2","readOnly":false,"hidden":false,"$$hashKey":"00C"}]},"table":"","$$hashKey":"008"}]}}

Comment: @AbrahamMathewAjoy: but then you have entirely different JSON, where apparently there's an array of `group` elements rather than a single one. You'll have to change your question to reflect that, because then it's no longer clear if you want to count rules over all groups, or per group, and how many groups are present per table row. SQL questions really benefit from showing input (including table structure) and desired output.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @Jeroen Mostert, i need to check all groups , Modified initial json string like that , please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ->

```
Select Count(*)
From mytable
WHERE JSON_VALUE(Serialized, '$.field')="F1"
```

Comment: It displays as 0 , which is not valid :(

Answer (score 0):

As an advice JSON data should not be stored it self.  You should make tables and columns depending on the data you are storing. Maybe make a database called group, with a table called operator, which would have three columns, operator, rule and rule value. So it would look something like this:

```
 Operator     Rule    RuleValue
 -------- ----------- ---------
|   #1   | condition |  =      |
|   #1   | field     |  f1     |
|   #1   | table     |  ATT    |
|   #2   | data      |  test   |
```

You can change the table to your needs but remember JSON and XML is a way of storing data in files. So when storing data in database, you shouldn't store it in XMl or JSON